# Hide geolocation of embedded map from user

Tags: javascript, encryption, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed a googlemap in a page but I don't want the user to be able to determine the geolocation by inspecting the code.

I've tried using the Javascript API to insert the map and loading in the Geolocation in a separate JS file which has been minified but the lon-lat are still easily identified.

Any tips on how I might go about doing this?

p.s. I know it sounds like a weird thing to want to do! It's for a puzzle and I don't want people to be able to cheat :-)

Comment: isn't the lat/lon part of the map URL? if so, there's nothing you can do to keep it out of devtools/firebug...

Comment: Ah sorry I should have mentioned I am rendering the map as a streetview panorama. As mentioned I then use the Javascript API to insert this onto a div. When I inspect that div I can't see the lat/lon anywhere unless I'm missing something?

Comment: ok, well if google isn't letting the cat out of the bag, you must be in your JS code. there's no perfect way to hide it from everyone. you can use danml.com/slim/  [Tools>Zip Input into Script] to turn your JS code into a self-unpacking zip, which removes all human-readability from the source. It can be reverse-engineered, but you will probably stop 99% of casual cheaters. If you do that, insert "eval" (no quotes) before the generated zip code when you save it. You could also use slim's dataURL tool to generate a script .src property from your code...

Answer (score 0):

How about calling a service to get the geolocations? You could iterate over the results add the markers (I do it with `google.maps.event.addListener` to include a tooltip as well).

A user would have to inspect the result from the service.

If you want, you can use unique identifiers for your service calls, that are only valid once. A disadvantage would be that page refresh aren't possible anymore, because you would call the service with the same parameters again.